# window.addEventListener("message" ... not working with IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, addeventlistener

I am opening a popup and this one sent a postMessage to the opener one.
I have added a ListenerEvent to the main window for 'message' but this listener is never called in IE 11, it works with firefox.

I already try to wait for the window, or the trick to replace the eventListener by a setInterval but I can't access data of the event in this case. And I have check all the threads that are similar to my question.
So I just try a little and simple example to check that addEventListener 'message' is working with IE11 and it does not.

The script in my main html page :

```
var popup = window.open("popup.html", "Connection", 
                'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, menubar=no, status=yes, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, '
                + 'width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + y + ', left=' + x);
popup.postMessage("The user is 'bob' and the password is 'secret'",
                  "*");
                  },500);
```

The script in my popup html page :

```
function receiveMessage(event)
{
    alert("OK popup");
    console.log("djedjeidjeidjiejdie");
}
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

So for me, the result should be an alert window that is raised when opening the popup. This is the case with firefox but not with IE11. Don't understand why.

Comment: What if you wait for your popup to have loaded? `popup.onload = function() { popup.postMessage(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make a test with code below. It is working with IE 11.

Main page code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script>
    //create popup window
var domain = 'http://example.com';
var myPopup = window.open(domain + '/HTML/popup_page.html','myWindow');

//periodical message sender
setInterval(function(){
    var message = 'Hello!  The time is: ' + (new Date().getTime());
    console.log('blog.local:  sending message:  ' + message);
    myPopup.postMessage(message,domain); //send the message and target URI
},6000);

//listen to holla back
window.addEventListener('message',function(event) {
    if(event.origin !== 'http://example.com') return;
    console.log('received response:  ',event.data);
},false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Main page</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Popup page code:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.addEventListener('message',function(event) {
    if (event.origin !== 'http://example.com') return;
    alert("OK popup");
    console.log('message received:  ' + event.data,event);
    event.source.postMessage('holla back youngin!',event.origin);
},false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>popup_page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE:

[image]

[image]

Note that you will also get an alert() while you run the code.

Reference:

[HTML5’s window.postMessage API](https://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage)

Comment: This was not working because I use a path to a static file in the browser: "C://..../main.html". If I call page through a server 'http://main.html" it works in IE 11